# Bootstrap 4 layout help - get columns to expand to correct heights

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am trying to design a site. First time using bootstrap and I just cant figure out editing the heights properly and I feel like I just started learning coding from scratch. (I had taken a few years hiatus.)

I am trying to get the page to look like this on above tablet(portrait size)

**Above portrait size:**

[image]

My goal for the larger size was to have the main body take up about 80% of the window and the footer/header take up the rest of the space.

And trying to get it to look like this on the tablet(portrait) and smaller:

**Below portrait size:**

[image]

My goal for this one was not to just have it go down below the image and make it scroll-able.

Right now my code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <title>The Last Names</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Caitlyn &amp; Jacob Team Up</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">The Bridal Party</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">RSVP</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registry</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    
      <!-- Pictures will go here -->
      <div class="picmain col-12 col-md-6 bg-primary">
        <h3>pics here</h3>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Info column row -->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">

          <!-- info 1 -->
          <div class="info1 col-12 bg-secondary">
            <h3>info1</h3>
          </div>

          <!-- info 2 -->
          <div class="info2 col-12 bg-info">
            <h3>info2</h3>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer col-12">Footer stuff will go here</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

can anyone help me figure out what I need to do to achieve what I was hoping for?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do on the body is to create a row with two columns and in the second column you nest 2 rows(each row having a class "col"). Check this pen example
`

```
 <!--General Row starts here --> 
    <div class="row">
      <!--first column starts here --> 
      <div class="col-md one ">
         <h1>Column </h1>
      </div>
      <!--first column ends here -->
      <!--second column starts here -->
       <div class="col-md">
         <!--first nested row starts here -->
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col  two">
             <h1> first Nested row with "col" class</h1>
           </div>
         </div>
 <!--first nested row ends here -->
 <!--second nested row starts here -->
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col three">
               <h1> second Nested row with "col" class </h1>
             </div>
         </div>
<!--second nested row ends here -->
         </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

` https://codepen.io/stevegates/pen/MPmRBp
and also check out the bootstrap docs for more information on bootstrap grid
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: That doesnt let me control the height though. that would just add another row's worth of height. correct?

Comment: @alphelm not really. The row is to let you have control over the content and structure of your page.  also from what I have experience in bootstrap 4 the height will automatically adjust depending on the content of the `col-*` since it uses flex-box . You can you use padding(top and bottom) to adjust the height accordingly depending on the content(Texts or Images). 
PS: Sorry if I didn't understand your question well.